# Local Mamp hosted Wordpress site can't connect to activate license of plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, localhost

This is a question regarding my local install of wordpress.

I am running Mamp to host wordpress on my Mac. As it is a multisite, I am using an Apache Web server (Ports 80, 3306).

I have a purchased plugin that requires an activation key. When I try to activate it, I get a message telling me that "Connection failed to the License Key API server" - seemingly due to the fact that my local server is is not able to connect to the internet and send the API request. On my live site, I can enter the license key and connect fine.

Where should I be looking in my localhost/php/configuration settings to remedy this issue?

Comment: While generating API key did it asked for domain name?

Comment: Hi Sushant,  No - asks for my login "credentials" which is a license key and my email address. Could it also be something to do with cURL? I don't know where to start with cURL though